# What is the stubname for fields with multiple separators?

Tags: python, pandas, field-names, long-format-data, wide-format-data

I'm trying to use pd.wide_to_long and I'm a little bit stumped on using the stubnames parameter:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html

Here are the field names:
[image]

**Expected behavior**: the transformation of a wide format df to a long format.

**Current behavior**: returns an empty row df with no other changes. I believe it's because of an improper use of stubnames or the sep parameter.

Attempts:

- stubnames = "0.outbreakMap."
- stubnames = "0.outbreakMap"
- stubnames = "outbreakMap"
- stubnames = "outbreakMap."

Thank you.

Comment: kindly share the dataframe as text, and also share the expected output datataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to swap `i` and `j` then specify the suffix (wildcard):

```
>>> pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='0.outbreakMap', i='reportInfoId', j='id', 
                    sep='.', suffix='.*').reset_index()

   reportInfoId                            id 0.outbreakMap
0          2428       1000011041.oieReference    1000011041
1          2428  1000011041.outbreakStartDate    2010-02-03


>>> df
   reportInfoId  0.outbreakMap.1000011041.oieReference 0.outbreakMap.1000011041.outbreakStartDate
0          2428                             1000011041                                 2010-02-03
```

Comment: Works perfectly! So I had multiple issues going on which I would never have known without your help. Using the right stubname, suffix with a wildcard to grab everything after it, and swapping some parameter values around. Thank you!