# Using pd.wide_to_long and having the sep= be parenthesis, getting empty dataframe with the column names only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do pd.wide_to_long and I want to separate based off of what is inside a parenthesis. I looked up the pandas manual [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long) and the closes example is below. I changed the column names to match something to what I have.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A(weekly_2010)': np.random.rand(3),
                   'A(weekly_2011)': np.random.rand(3),
                   'B(weekly_2010)': np.random.rand(3),
                   'B(weekly_2011)': np.random.rand(3),
                   'X' : np.random.randint(3, size=3)})
df['id'] = df.index
```

I would do

```
df1=pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['A', 'B'], i=['id'], j='year', sep='()', suffix='\w+')
```

This returns an empty dataframe. I looked at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72137046/what-is-the-stubname-for-fields-with-multiple-separators) and switched the i and J but it returns a KeyError: "None of [Index(['year'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
I have tried the following for sep= and still no luck. Does someone have an idea of how to get the following dataframe.

```
df1=pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['A', 'B'], i=['id'], j='year', sep='(*)', suffix='\w+')
df1=pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['A', 'B'], i=['id'], j='year', sep='\\()', suffix='\w+')
df1=pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['A', 'B'], i=['id'], j='year', sep=r'\\()', suffix='\w+')
df1=pd.wide_to_long(df11, stubnames=['A', 'B'], i=['id'], j='year', sep=r'\(*\)', suffix='\w+')
```

The desired dataframe would be

```
desiredDF= pd.DataFrame({'year':["(weekly_2010)","(weekly_2010)","(weekly_2010)","(weekly_2011)","(weekly_2011)","(weekly_2011)"],
               'A': np.random.rand(6),
               'B': np.random.rand(6),
               'X' : np.random.randint(6, size=6),
               'id':np.random.randint(6, size=6)})
```

obviously with the same numbers, I just wanted to show the column that matters which is the year column. I need to do pivot because my dataframe is more complicated and doing other formats, messes up the numbers. If anyone knows how to write in the sep, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, remove the trailing close parenthesis and separate on open parenthesis:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(')','', regex=False)
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['A', 'B'], i=['id'], j='year', sep='(', suffix='\w+')
```

Output:

```
                X         A         B
id year                              
0  weekly_2010  0  0.548814  0.437587
1  weekly_2010  1  0.715189  0.891773
2  weekly_2010  1  0.602763  0.963663
0  weekly_2011  0  0.544883  0.383442
1  weekly_2011  1  0.423655  0.791725
2  weekly_2011  1  0.645894  0.528895
```

I find that sometimes you need to do a little prep work to get pd.wide_to_long to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

@ScottBoston's solution works well. I'd suggest an alternative to `pd.wide_to_long` that offers more flexibility, while still being performant -  [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index=['X', 'id'], 
                names_to = ('.value', 'year'), 
                names_pattern=r"(.)(.+)") 
   X  id           year         A         B
0  0   0  (weekly_2010)  0.548814  0.437587
1  1   1  (weekly_2010)  0.715189  0.891773
2  1   2  (weekly_2010)  0.602763  0.963663
3  0   0  (weekly_2011)  0.544883  0.383442
4  1   1  (weekly_2011)  0.423655  0.791725
5  1   2  (weekly_2011)  0.645894  0.528895
```

The `.value` in this case tells the function to keep that part of the column as a header. This is determined by the argument passed to `names_pattern` or `names_sep`.

Sticking to `pd.wide_to_long`, simply use the generic `.+` regex for the `suffix` parameter:

```py
pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                stubnames = ['A','B'], 
                i = 'id', 
                j = 'year', 
                sep='', 
                suffix='.+') 
                  X         A         B
id year                                
0  (weekly_2010)  0  0.548814  0.437587
1  (weekly_2010)  1  0.715189  0.891773
2  (weekly_2010)  1  0.602763  0.963663
0  (weekly_2011)  0  0.544883  0.383442
1  (weekly_2011)  1  0.423655  0.791725
2  (weekly_2011)  1  0.645894  0.528895
```